# Sending Hex Values Using Chr() Is Adding Unknown Bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to send files over a serial connection (from another open-source project). I'm getting stuck on sending large files, however. The file length does not convert properly.

I use an int array by declaring

```
encoded = []
```

Then the file length is found. Something like

```
fileLength = 114872
```

When I encode this I get an unexpected output. Obviously, for this number we expect "[0x00][0x01][0xC0][0xB8]"

```
encoded.append(chr((fileLength >> 24) & 0xFF));
encoded.append(chr((fileLength >> 16) & 0xFF));
encoded.append(chr((fileLength >> 8) & 0xFF));
encoded.append(chr((fileLength >> 0) & 0xFF));
```

But when I print out encoded byte by byte using

```
print("".join(str(v) for v in encoded).encode())
```

I get:

```
\x00\x01\xc3\x80\xc2\xb8
```

Sending the hex values over serial in this manner does not get send as the correct bytes. Using:

```
encoded.append(hex((fileLength >> 24) & 0xFF));
encoded.append(hex((fileLength >> 16) & 0xFF));
encoded.append(hex((fileLength >> 8) & 0xFF));
encoded.append(hex((fileLength >> 0) & 0xFF));
```

This gives the expected result:

```
0x00x10xc00xb8
```

But this string is unrecognizable when transferring over serial. Why does the chr() function return 16 bytes, despite the fact that I am even masking off all but the first 8 bytes?

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Check my answer and see if it helps you @andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [int.to_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes)

```
In [11]: x = (114872).to_bytes(4, byteorder='big')                              

In [12]: x                                                                      
Out[12]: b'\x00\x01\xc0\xb8'

In [13]: for i in x: 
    ...:     print(i) 
    ...:                                                                        
0
1
192
184
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still causes it to be sent as individual bytes. What I see across the logic analyzer is:
[0][1][1][9][2] etc.

Trying to just transfer 'x' also just transfers the individual characters. The output is:
[b]['][\\][x][0][0][\\][x][0][1] etc.

Comment: So there are probably many ways to do this, but after agonizing over the steps, I found that I have to set these up separately, rather than encode them as part of the print() command. Otherwise, everything gets converted to a character, rather than as a byte and not all libraries are unicode compatible.

So instead I have done this:

    print(fileLength.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))

And similarly

    ser.write(fileLength.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))

Comment: So int.to_bytes did work finally, yes it gives you a byte string and you can write it over a serial port